# How can i make a deterministic match-3 puzzle game algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, match, game-development

I am making a match-3 puzzle game (like candy crush) and i am looking for an algorithm to make my grid deterministic.

For some reason i need to get the same result whatever the player does.

I would like to be able to set a parameter like "in this grid, the player will harvest 18 red balls and a maximum of 10 of the other colors", and whatever the player will do, when he will have played every move he can do in any order, he will have harvested 18 red balls and a maximum of 10 of the other balls.

The grid will also refill when balls are destroyed, so i will probably have a tree like if i play this move then spawn "red red blue", but if i play this move instead then spawn "blue yellow red".

I can't find a good way to do this, help :)

edit:

Rules of the game:

- 6*6 grid
- 5 different colors
- colors can match by line and column
- they match if they are at least 3
- a match remove the matching colors
- when a color is removed, the colors above it fall to fill the hole, the new colors are created at the top of the grid
- there is no special effects (for now)

Comment: This seems quite broad. *"like candy crush"*: please define exactly the rules, and provide an actual example input. Also show your work so far.

Comment: Without making the grid quite boring (e.g. one block of 18 reds, no other matches possible), your constraints will often be impossible to guarantee in all possible game paths. Even if you narrow down your constraints, this is very similar to many NP-hard problems.

Comment: What is a bullet?

Comment: What moves can the user make? Is it selecting two adjacent balls and swapping them? Can they only be swapped if that gives 3+ in a row?

Comment: What you ask for is a pretty tall order. You might want to take a look at the backpack problem. https://brilliant.org/wiki/backpack-problem/#:~:text=Applications-,Introduction,the%20capacity%20of%20your%20backpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above deals with the algorithmic science bits nicely. You need to nail down the rules. And, either you make the arrangement really constrained, such that you force the player down a certain path, or you solve some very hefty combinatorial problem to ensure that your path manifests.

So, maybe, take a step back: "deterministic" and "game" are not a good combination: It's not really a game, if you know the outcome in advance!

The premise brings to mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stanley_Parable - which explores the idea of a game providing a deterministic path, and what the player chooses to do when presented with that.

Perhaps, rephrase, and *make* the game to reach "18 red / 10 others" and if the player does not achieve that, then, Game Over Try Again..